# Aggregating transducers with intermediate values

Tags: clojure, transducer

I am still trying to understand better how to work with transducers in clojure. Here, I am interested in applying aggregating transducers, such as the ones in https://github.com/cgrand/xforms, but reporting at each step the intermediate values of the computation.

For instance, the following expression

```clj
(sequence (x/into #{}) [1 2 3])
```

yields `(#{1 2 3})`, which is only the final value of the reduction. Now, I would be interested in an transducer `xf-incremental` that given something like

```clj
(sequence (comp xf-incremental (x/into #{})) [1 2 3])
```

yields `(#{1} #{1 2} #{1 2 3})`.

The reason why I am interested in this is that I want to report intermediate values of a metric that aggregates over the history of processed values.

Any idea how can I do something of the sort in a generic way?

EDIT: Think of (x/into #{}) as an arbitrary transducer that aggregates results. Better examples could be x/avg or (x/reduce +) where I would expect

```clj
(sequence (comp xf-incremental x/avg) [1 2 3])
(sequence (comp xf-incremental (x/reduce +)) [1 2 3])
```

to return `(1 3/2 2)` and `(1 3 6)` respectively.

EDIT 2: another way of phrasing this is that I want a transducer that performs a reducing function and returns the accumulator at each step, which also can reuse all the available transducers so I do not need to rewrite basic functionalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution using clojure.core/reductions**

You don't need a transducer to perform the computation that you are asking for. The function you are looking for to see all the intermediate results of `reduce` is called `reductions` and you provide it with `conj` and an empty set as arguments:

```
(rest (reductions conj #{} [1 2 3]))
;; => (#{1} #{1 2} #{1 3 2})
```

`rest` removes the first empty set, because that was the output you requested in the original question.

The function that builds up the result here is `conj`, lets refer to it as a *step function*. A *transducer* is a function that takes a step function as input and returns a new step function as output. So if we want to combine `reductions` with a transducer, we can just apply the transducer to `conj`:

```
(def my-transducer (comp (filter odd?)
                         (take 4)))

(dedupe (reductions (my-transducer conj) #{} (range)))
;; => (#{} #{1} #{1 3} #{1 3 5} #{7 1 3 5})
```

`dedupe` is there just to remove elements that are equal to preceding elements. You can remove it if you don't want to do that. In that case you get the following, because that is how the filtering transducer works:

```
(reductions (my-transducer conj) #{} (range)))
;; => (#{} #{} #{1} #{1} #{1 3} #{1 3} #{1 3 5} #{1 3 5} #{7 1 3 5})
```

**Transducer-based solution using net.cgrand.xforms/reductions**

Apparently, there is also a *transducer* version of `reductions` in the xforms library, which is closer to your initial code:

```
(require '[net.cgrand.xforms :as xforms])

(rest (sequence (xforms/reductions conj #{}) [1 2 3]))
;; => (#{1} #{1 2} #{1 3 2})
```

This `xforms/reductions` transducer can be composed with other transducer using `comp` to for example filter odd numbers and taking the first four of them:

```
(sequence (comp (filter odd?)
                (take 4)
                (xforms/reductions conj #{}))

          (range))
;; => (#{} #{1} #{1 3} #{1 3 5} #{7 1 3 5})
```

In this case, you don't need `dedupe`. It is also possible to use other step functions with `xforms/reductions`, e.g. `+`:

```
(sequence (comp (filter odd?)
                (take 10)
                (xforms/reductions + 0)
                (filter #(< 7 %)))

          (range))
;; => (9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I would like to clarify that using transducers is important in this case because I am using them to extract metrics from a sequence of input values that come from a channel, which I then feed into another channel. The thing is that I also want to get intermediate values of these metrics. So, now imagine that rather than just adding elements to a set, I want to apply a few operations to them. Like, incrementing and filtering odd ones. How can I do so?

Comment: See the last code snippet for an example of how you can combine `xforms/reductions` with for example a filtering transducer and a taking transducer.